# SchemaError Pushing Ruby on Rails to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to push my application to Heroku and I'm running into a SchemaError. I'm not sure what it means by ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RAILS_8A77483D84". And my development Active Record database seems to working just fine. I have added the error, active record queries below, my Schema.db and CreateMicroposts.rb file.

```
== 20141231063907 CreateMicroposts: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:microposts)
 (109.2ms)  CREATE TABLE "microposts" ("id" serial primary key, "content" text, "user_id"        integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) 
 (50.1ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_microposts_on_user_id" ON "microposts"  ("user_id")
 -> 0.1634s
-- add_foreign_key(:microposts, [:user_id, :created_at])
(4.2ms)  ALTER TABLE "microposts" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_9d9d4880ea"
FOREIGN KEY ("[:user_id, :created_at]_id")
REFERENCES "[:user_id,".":created_at]" ("id")

PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  schema "[:user_id," does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "microposts" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_9d9d4880ea"
FOREIGN KEY ("[:user_id, :created_at]_id")
REFERENCES "[:user_id,".":created_at]" ("id")
```

**Active Record Query, has a user_id attached.**

```
2.1.4 :001 > Micropost.first
 Micropost Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts"  ORDER BY                        "microposts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Micropost id: 303, content: "Sewer", user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-01-01 00:56:34", updated_at: "2015-01-01 00:56:34", picture: "IMG_7206.jpg"> 
2.1.4 :002 > User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at: "2014-12-31 07:28:36", updated_at: "2014-12-31 07:28:36", password_digest: "$2a$10$uVp2u1r6wiWc0f6Gqwx5BOdKjt6a165cbb82VrunsSI...", remember_digest: nil, admin: true, activation_digest: "$2a$10$waWyAykqx2QbYdWG0wPEMen5elWR62Rxw94Lpcfx73S...", activated: true, activated_at: "2014-12-31 07:28:36", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil>
```

**Schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150101001952) do

create_table "microposts", force: true do |t|
 t.text     "content"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string   "picture"
end

add_index "microposts", ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.string   "email"
 t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
 t.string   "password_digest"
 t.string   "remember_digest"
 t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
 t.string   "activation_digest"
 t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
 t.datetime "activated_at"
 t.string   "reset_digest"
 t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

**Microposts**

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
     t.text :content
     t.references :user, index: true
     t.timestamps null: false
   end
  add_foreign_key :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
 end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that is my schema.rb. The application pushed to heroku just fine, but I'm trying to run- Heroku run rake db:migrate. I first ran Heroku heroku pg:reset DATABASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just using `add_foreign_key` incorrectly and [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) is assuming that you know what you're doing. The [docs say that `add_foreign_key`](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner#api-examples) is used like this:

```
add_foreign_key(from_table, to_table, options)
```

If we compare that with your migration:

```
add_foreign_key :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

we see that `from_table` is `:microposts` and `to_table` is the array `[:user_id, :created_at]`. If you call `to_s` on that array, you'll get the odd looking mess that ends up the SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE "microposts" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_9d9d4880ea"
FOREIGN KEY ("[:user_id, :created_at]_id")
--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
REFERENCES "[:user_id,".":created_at]" ("id")
--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Presumably you just want to have `microposts.user_id` as an FK which references `users.id`. That means that you'd want to say:

```
add_foreign_key :microposts, :users
```

and foreigner should figure out the referencing column and name and the referenced table name all by itself.

Comment: Thanks Mu! When I generated my migration I guess it added the foreign key part in. I'm pretty new to all of this - your explanation is very helpful!